# YoutTube iFrame API bug on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube, youtube-api

I was adding a video on my page using YouTube's iFrame API *with autoplay set to `true`*.

Turns out that autoplay was not working *only* in Chrome, unless I had the console opened.

Firefox and Safari are auto playing normally.

I've tried that in a private tab, different screens resolutions but nothing except the console opened seems to solve this issue.

My Chrome is updated and without extensions.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Answer (score 0):

Try define your video with muted
example:

```
<video autoplay playsinline="playsinline" loop="loop" muted>
    <source src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/youyvideo.mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: As I'm using the JavaScript API, I couldn't do that. Although calling `event.target.mute();` on my "player ready" function seems to work. Can you also put the example in your code so that other people see how to do that using the JS api?